# PowerShell problems with Collection.Where() method

Tags: powershell, where-clause, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The following code works in v4 but not in v3.

```
$Running,$Stopped = (Get-Service).Where({$_.Status -eq 'Running'},'Split')
```

How can I rewrite it to get it running in v3 and giving the same result?

Comment: `$srv = Get-Service | group Status -AsHashTable -AsString` might be close and for *some* use-cases even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split expression (all versions):

```
$Running = Get-Service | ? {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}
$Stopped = Get-Service | ? {$_.Status -ne 'Running'}
```

Or, as noted by @wOxxOm, in V3:

```
$Running = Get-Service | ? Status -eq 'Running'
$Stopped = Get-Service | ? Status -ne 'Running'
```

Comment: In PS3 `where` can compare directly: `Get-Service | ? Status -eq 'Running'`